# Better filters for range hood fan?

Tags: kitchens

We have an externally vented Whirlpool fan, WVU57UC6FS. I do clean the aluminum filters every few months (they never get very dirty), but the fan itself has a decent amount of trapped grease that sometimes drips down. Not great - and we've only had it a couple of years. We don't cook much greasy food, we almost never fry things. This seems weird.

I'm going to cut the breaker and clean out the fan itself but I'd like to avoid this happening again. Since the filters themselves never look that dirty, it seems like they're not really doing their job right.

Is there an upgrade option for these filters? I know they make charcoal filters, but those are intended for when you can't externally vent the fan exhaust and it's in recirculating mode.

Answer (score 3):

Aluminum mesh filters evidently let aerosolized grease through. If you make the pores finer, then the fan cannot pull sufficient air through and this might burn out the motor.

The better quality hoods have an entirely different system for collecting grease. Our 35 year old VentAHood has no filter. The squirrel cage fan compresses the greasy air flow and causes the grease to collect on the inside surface of the fan enclosure. Cleaning is by removal of the enclosure, pouring off the grease, wiping more grease, then soaking in hot water with detergent.

A friend has a near restaurant quality stainless steel hood in which the grease collects on SS panels which can be removed for cleaning.

I think the best you can do with the aluminum mesh type is to clean the mesh often and then maybe periodically wipe off the fan blades with paper towels or rag with orange oil or other non toxic degreaser.

Is the fan a propeller type or squirrel cage? IIRC in 35  years I have cleaned the squirrel cage fan in ours just once, and it was not easy.

EDIT

I looked up the model and read (scanned) the use and care manual. It looks like a high quality hood; the metal grease filter screens might be (and are probably are) stainless steel. They do refer to using charcoal filters resting on top of the metal filters (i.e., following in the direction of air flow) but only in the context of setting this up as a recirculating hood (without a vent to outside). You could contact the mfgr and ask about using the charcoal filter in the vented setup.

My friend with the restaurant quality SS hood complained to me that his hood didn't have a filter, and he thought he had an inferior appliance. I knew he had an Aga gas range with electric oven and told him that the previousowner who put in the Aga would surely have installed a fine hood. When I researched it sure enough it was an American made hood perfect for high grease cooking on his 36" Aga.

I wonder if dripping grease might be due to the modern practice of cooking with low congealing temperature vegetable oils (olive, corn, canola, etc.) rather than lard or solid vegetable shortening. Our VentAHood collects the oil in a reservoir, it can't drip down. VentAHood used this as a selling point. My friend's restaurant hood doesn't have a reservoir AFIK but it may have something that functions that way. I know it is supposed to be cleaned often.

EDIT2

IIRC the grease collection in my friend's hood is one or a pair of these side by side. Captive Aire Stainless Steel Restaurant Hood [grease collector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KVKMJ1F)

EDIT3

[These are](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09XD53B2S) advertised as an upgraded filter for Whirlpool and some other hoods. Might fit with no added adaptor. Might control dripping.

Comment: "Is the fan a propeller type or squirrel cage?" - I dunno yet, that's not in the user manual and I haven't yet taken it apart.

Comment: Propellor vs. squirrel cage should be very easy to tell if you can see any of the moving parts of the fan.

Comment: @JimStewart the manufacturer has not included this detail in their manual, and the only other filter they mention is a charcoal one for the scenario of recirculating. This is why I asked the question here. I'm absolutely going to take it apart so I can get it cleaned, as I stated in my question.

Comment: Their support is also useless. I wrote up my issue for them and they replied "have you tried looking at our support site? Would you like to schedule a tech visit?" https://producthelp.whirlpool.com/Product_Help_Page?model=WVU57UC6FS

Comment: Looks to me like you could fabricate a rim that the  restaurant type of grease filter would lock into. I think my friend's filter might be held in by its own weight but can not remember. IIRC to remove it you lift up on one end, then it comes free on the other end, and is manipulated by two gripping handles. Of course, you would have to determine if there would be interference in your hood. What are the L and W on your metal screens? Two of them? Is yours a 30" or a 36" wide hood?

Comment: See EDIT3 for upgraded filter for Whirlpool hood that might be an improvement over your current filters. Not in the same class as the restaurant hood collector, but would presumably be a direct replacement for the existing filter.

Comment: [Squirrel cage - see parts diagram, # 8](https://www.appliancepartspros.com/hood-parts-parts-for-whirlpool-wvu57uc6fs0.html)

Comment: IMO this suggests that the dripping is not from the fan itself because a squirrel cage should fling off any liquid which collected on it. The dripping could be from the fan shroud or the grille in front of the fan. Either way an upgraded filter might retain oil drips better than the original filter. Is the original a thin screen or does it have depth to it? Is there a geometrical pattern to the drips--is it in the center or in a rectangle?